# Pass array/list from bash script to ansible loop

Tags: bash, loops, ansible

I have a simple goal in mind which I thought should be trivial, but does not seem so. I have a list of unknown names in bash, e.g. instances="i1,i2,i3" and need to iterate over them in Ansible's role, which looks like this:

```
- name My name
  shell: "runServer {{item}}"
  loop: "{{ my_instances }}"
```

I also tried to use with_items as well:

```
- name My name
  shell: "runServer {{item}}"
  with_items: "{{ my_instances }}"
```

where my_instances is a variable I am trying to construct based on the instances mentioned above. I tried so far few approaches:

1. use `--extra_vars "instances='i1,i2,i3'"`
2. use `--extra_vars "instances=['i1','i2','i3']"` where instances are constructed in outside Rundeck job's bash shell as a bash array
3. use `--extra_vars "{instances:['i1','i2','i3']}"`
4. use `--extra_vars "instances='i1,i2,i3'` and inside my main job in the var section attempted to convert it to the list like this:
   `my_instances: "{{ instances.split(',') | list }}"` In all cases I was simply declaring `my_instances: "{{ instances }}"`
5. use
   `loop: "{{ query('my_instances', 'all') }}"` in the role along with 1-4
   (In all other cases above I was simply declaring variable as my_instances: '{{ instances }}' in var section)

Regardless of my tries I always get the same dreadful error. Can somebody explain me what I am doing wrong and how to iterate over items in role's playbook (main.yml) where loop var is coming from outside bash shell (in my case Rundeck's bash shell) ? I am running out ideas.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: for your 4th point: use `with_items: "{{ my_instances.split(',') }}"` and supply bash list as `-e my_instances='i1','i2','i3'`

Answer (score 0):

`--extra-vars` is an argument and it's not needed use `=` after of it. And when you use `wiht_items` or `loop` it's necessary use a list and this is constructed as your second approach:

```
--extra_vars "instances=['i1','i2','i3']"
```

Comment: Yes, my bad. I have edited original post. That's not a problem, the script does not have = after --extra_vars.